# oracle select from multiple tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have function which will return mi home or away if the p_search_string is same as those fields.

```
    FUNCTION SEARACH_FOR_GAMES  ( p_search_string in varchar2 )
                             return weak_cur
  IS
    SEARCH_FIXID WEAK_CUR;   
  BEGIN  
    OPEN   SEARCH_FIXID FOR
select  HOME,AWAY,COMP_NAME, M_TIME from SOCCER s
where s.HOME LIKE (:p_search_string) or s.AWAY LIKE (:p_search_string)
union all
select  HOME,AWAY,LISTS,M_TIME from BASKETBALL b
where b.HOME LIKE (:p_search_string) or b.AWAY LIKE (:p_search_string)
union all
select HOME,AWAY,COMP,M_TIME from HANDBALL h
where h.HOME LIKE (:p_search_string) or h.AWAY LIKE (:p_search_string)
union all
select  HOME,AWAY,LISTS,M_TIME from ICE_HOCKEY i
where i.HOME LIKE (:p_search_string) or i.AWAY LIKE (:p_search_string)
union all
select  HOME,AWAY,COMP,M_TIME from TENISt
where t.HOME LIKE (:p_search_string) or t.AWAY LIKE (:p_search_string)
union all
select  HOME,AWAY,LISTS,M_TIME from VOLLEYBALL v
where v.HOME LIKE (:p_search_string) or v.AWAY LIKE (:p_search_string);
    RETURN SEARCH_FIXID;
  END SEARACH_FOR_GAMES;
```

This works fine, but i m wondering is there a "nicer" way to write down these selects ?

Thanks

Comment: I would claim that your data model is maybe the problem.  Since we don't see your table definitions, hard to say, but Having one table per sport type is not a good model.  Sport type should be an attribute/column of a table, not individual tables.  WHat happens when you need to add another sport?  Create a new table?

Comment: Have a single table called `game_schedules` and another table `sport` for soccer, tennis etc with an id `sport_id` which is referenced by a  foreign key in `game_schedules`. You may then join these 2 tables in  a single select(without multiple union alls)  for your cursor.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an issue with the data model as far as this requirement is concerned. I can suggest two options:

**Option# 1:**
Create a single table SPORTS by combining all tables and have a column sport_type. This will allow to use one select query in function.

```
select  HOME,AWAY,COMP_NAME, M_TIME from SPORTS s
where s.HOME LIKE (:p_search_string) or s.AWAY LIKE (:p_search_string)
  and sport_type in 
(
'SOCCER',
'BASKETBALL',
'HANDBALL',
'ICE_HOCKEY',
'TENIST',
'VOLLEYBALL'
)
```

**Option# 2:**

```
Create a view by combining all these tables and select from that view in this function.
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_SPORTS
AS
select HOME,AWAY,COMP_NAME, M_TIME, 'SOCCER' SPORT_TYPE from SOCCER
union all
select  HOME,AWAY,LISTS,M_TIME,'BASKETBALL' SPORT_TYPE from BASKETBALL 
union all
select HOME,AWAY,COMP,M_TIME,'HANDBALL' SPORT_TYPE from HANDBALL
union all
select  HOME,AWAY,LISTS,M_TIME,'ICE_HOCKEY' SPORT_TYPE from ICE_HOCKEY
union all
select  HOME,AWAY,COMP,M_TIME,'TENIST' SPORT_TYPE from TENISt
union all
select  HOME,AWAY,LISTS,M_TIME,'VOLLEYBALL' SPORT_TYPE  from VOLLEYBALL v;


 FUNCTION SEARACH_FOR_GAMES  ( p_search_string in varchar2 )
                             return weak_cur
  IS
    SEARCH_FIXID WEAK_CUR;   
  BEGIN  
    OPEN   SEARCH_FIXID FOR
       select  HOME,AWAY,COMP_NAME, M_TIME from VW_SPORTS s
        where s.HOME LIKE (:p_search_string) or s.AWAY LIKE (:p_search_string)
         and s.SPOR_TYPE IN 
    (
    'SOCCER',
    'BASKETBALL',
    'HANDBALL',
    'ICE_HOCKEY',
    'TENIST',
    'VOLLEYBALL'
    );
    RETURN SEARCH_FIXID;
  END SEARACH_FOR_GAMES;
```

Comment: All these sport tables are external tables. Would that be problem if I create one table to hold all data ..