# Oracle cursor error with if statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I m getting error when try to create this procedure in packages.

```
FUNCTION SEARACH_FOR_GAMES (p_search_string in varchar2, p_match_type in number )
                             return weak_cur
  IS
    SEARCH_FIXID WEAK_CUR;   
  BEGIN  


    if p_match_type = 2
    then 
    OPEN   SEARCH_FIXID FOR
        select  FIXID, HOME,AWAY,COMP_NAME, M_TIME from SOCCER s
        where s.HOME LIKE (p_search_string) or s.AWAY LIKE (p_search_string)
        union all
        select  FIXID,HOME,AWAY,LISTS,M_TIME from BASKETBALLb
        where b.HOME LIKE (p_search_string) or b.AWAY LIKE (p_search_string)
        union all
        select FIXID,HOME,AWAY,COMP,M_TIME from HANDBALL h
        where h.HOME LIKE (p_search_string) or h.AWAY LIKE (p_search_string);
   elsif p_match_type = 1
    then
    OPEN   SEARCH_FIXID FOR
        select  FIXID,HOME,AWAY,COMP_NAME, TIME from LIVE_MATCHES_TZ s
        where s.HOME LIKE (p_search_string) or s.AWAY LIKE (p_search_string)
        union all
        select  FIXID,HOME,AWAY,COMP_NAME,TIME from LIVE_BASKETBALL_MATCHES b
        where b.HOME LIKE (p_search_string) or b.AWAY LIKE (p_search_string)
        union all
        select FIXID,HOME,AWAY,COMP_NAME,TIME from LIVE_HANDBALL_MATCHES h
        where h.HOME LIKE (p_search_string) or h.AWAY LIKE (p_search_string);
    end if;

    RETURN SEARCH_FIXID;
  END SEARACH_FOR_GAMES;
```

i get two errors  Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following and Encountered the symbol "end-of-file". 
Could it be because of it cursor  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [oracle select from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645492/oracle-select-from-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 0):

It must be like this:

```
if p_match_type = 0 then
    OPEN SEARCH_FIXID FOR
    select  FIXID,HOME,AWAY,COMP_NAME, M_TIME 
    from SOCCERs
    where s.HOME LIKE (p_search_string) or s.AWAY LIKE (p_search_string)
        ...
```

In order to use the cursor you must check it with

```
cur := PCK_BET.SEARACH_FOR_GAMES('xyz', 1);
IF cur%IS_OPEN THEN
    ...
ELSE
    -- No cursor opened
END ID;
```

Comment: But what if i have another IF under this ..

if p_match_type = 1
    then
select  FIXID,HOME,AWAY,COMP_NAME, M_TIME from TABLE1 s
where s.HOME LIKE (p_search_string) or s.AWAY LIKE (p_search_string)
union all
select  FIXID,HOME,AWAY,LISTS,M_TIME from TABLE2 b
where b.HOME LIKE (p_search_string) or b.AWAY LIKE (p_search_string)

end if;
I dont need to open cursor again ?

Comment: No, of course not. I am just too lazy to copy all of your big query.

Comment: But when do not put open cursor in THEN i get error an INTO clause is expected in this select

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
open cursorname for select...;
```

not

```
open cursorname;

for
    [...procedural logic...]
```

Since we can rely on the optimiser to push predicates like this into a view, I would write it as something like this:

```
create or replace function search_for_games
    ( p_search_string   in varchar2
    , p_match_type      in number )
    return sys_refcursor
is
    search_results sys_refcursor;
begin
    open search_results for
        select fixid, home, away, comp_name, m_time
        from   (
                 -- Type 0 matches:
                 select 0 as matchtype, fixid, home, away, comp_name, m_time from soccers
                 union all
                 select 0 as matchtype, fixid, home, away, comp_name, m_time from basketballb
                 union all
                 select 0 as matchtype, fixid, home, away, comp_name, m_time from handball h
                 union all
                 select 0 as matchtype, fixid, home, away, comp_name, m_time from ice_hockey i
                 union all
                 select 0 as matchtype, fixid, home, away, comp_name, m_time from tenis t
                 union all
                 select 0 as matchtype, fixid, home, away, comp_name, m_time from volleyball v
                 union all
                 -- Type 1 matches:
                 select 1 as matchtype, fixid, home, away, comp_name, m_time from table1
                 union all
                 select 1 as matchtype, fixid, home, away, comp_name, m_time from table2
               ) m
        where  m.matchtype = p_match_type
        and    ( m.home like p_search_string or m.away like p_search_string );

    return search_results;
end search_for_games;
```

The `where` clause will get copied to individual sections as needed.

I'm not sure what logic you need to implement with the `p_match_type` parameter, but the structure above should be a start anyway.

Comment: I edited my code could you check it.. When i commented second    OPEN   SEARCH_FIXID FOR where p_match_type = 1 i get error that i need insert into statement.
But it works fine with these open cursors in elsif statement..

Comment: I think the `IF` condition is faster than your query.

Comment: I can't really see why it would be. But in any case, the OP wanted to avoid repeat cursor assignments, and this structure enforces consistency.